# Proof explanation in Mathematical Problems in Elasticity and Homogenization (Oleinik et al.)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the book *Mathematical Problems in Elasticity and Homogenization* by Oleinik, Shamaev and Yosifan. You can find the passage here https://books.google.de/books?id=WbJFaB0zxVMC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false on page 14/15 or have a look at the attached screenshots.

The author states [lemma 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlWHP.png) and [proves it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XddRa.png). Here is a short summary: Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain, $\rho(x) = dist(x, \partial \Omega), \delta > 0, \Omega_\delta = \Omega \cap \{ x : \rho(x) > \delta\}$ and $v \in C^\infty(\Omega) \cap L^2(\Omega)$. The author says that the inequality
$$
 \int_{\Omega_\delta} (\rho(x) - \delta)^2 \vert \nabla v \vert^2 \ dx
 \le c_1 \left(
    \Vert v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)} \Vert (\rho - \delta) \vert \nabla v \vert \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}
    + \Vert v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)} \Vert (\rho - \delta)^2 \Delta v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}
 \right)
$$
implies the existence of a constant $c_2 >0$ which does not depend on $v$ such that
$$
 \Vert (\rho - \delta) \vert \nabla v \vert \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}
 \le c_2 \left(
   \Vert v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)} \Vert
+ \Vert (\rho - \delta)^2 \Delta v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}
\right)
.
$$
I understand how we got to the first inequality but I do not understand how we got from there to the second inequality. When we divide the first inequality by $\Vert (\rho - \delta) \vert \nabla v \vert \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}$ (we assume it is nonzero - otherwise the statement is trivial) on both sides we **almost** have the answer. We just have to show that there is a constant $c>0$ which does **not** depend on $v$ such that
$$
 \frac{\Vert v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}}{\Vert (\rho - \delta) \vert \nabla v \vert \Vert_{L^2(\Omega_\delta)}}
 \le c
.
$$
However this does not seem true. Of course the term is bounded since $v \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ but this bound depends on $v$. I tried introducing Friedrichs inequality but I have troubles since $v$ does not vanish on $\partial \Omega_\delta$. I have the feeling that I am missing an important detail.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: There's an inequality about numbers: $ab \leq a^2/2t + t b^2/2$, for $a, b, t > 0$. You can use this instead of dividing like you tried in contexts where you need to divide some but not all the terms, and reabsorb one of the terms into the left-hand side.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user in the comments pointed out all you have to do is apply the inequality
$$
 2ab \le t a^2 + t^{-1} b^2
$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t > 0$ to both summands in the right side of the first inequality.